# listview.ItemClick doesn't working in void AfterTextChanged

Tags: c#, controls

My IDE gives me an error on the **lstview**.
There is a red IntelliSense underline below the identifier (enclosed in ** in the source code below):

```
    public void AfterTextChanged(IEditable s)
    {

        **lstview**.ItemClick += (e) =>
        {
            Intent intent;
            switch (e.Position)
            {
                case 0:
                    intent = new Intent(this, typeof(NextAC));
                    intent.PutExtra("site's name", data[0]);
                    StartActivity(intent);
                    break;

                case 1:
                    intent = new Intent(this, typeof(NextAC));
                    intent.PutExtra("site's name", data[1]);
                    StartActivity(intent);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    intent = new Intent(this, typeof(NextAC));
                    intent.PutExtra("site's name", data[2]);
                    StartActivity(intent);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    intent = new Intent(this, typeof(NextAC));
                    intent.PutExtra("site's name", data[3]);
                    StartActivity(intent);
                    break;

            }
       }; 
    }
```

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: why is your click event being registered inside another event?  That is wrong.  you will create multiple click if this is called multiple times. This needs to be moved into the load event and initialized only once.

Comment: apparently the control's name is either not `lstview`, or it is not in scope. or xamarin's android UI resource compiler got it wrong. build it, and include the build error in your post.

Comment: this method body could be golfed to three lines, if you drop the switch block entirely and use `data[e.Position]` (as long as the range is always 0..3).

Comment: lstview is the id of the ListView, I want that the case work after the user searching something because I put this in AfterTextChanged and then it not working. What to do?